# /bin/mount gives permission denied - How to use Japanese strings in password.

Tags: linux, locale, share, mount

I am using the following command in putty and it returns permission denied -13.

/bin/mount -t cifs \\hostname\directory  -o unc=\\hostname\folder,ip=,user=test,pass=eｦﾋ*1ajk,ver=1

If I use English password it works fine(for different user share).

I need know how to provide Japanese characters in putty (Any suggestion for other tools also welcome)

Both machines where the share directory exists and where we access are Japanese locale set.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Naga

Comment: Only a fool would use Kanji in their password and expect it to work. Simply don't use Kanji in your password and you'll be fine. This question also seems to be grossly off-topic here in Stack Overflow, please consider using Super User for questions not related to programming.

Comment: I just used char map to find some random Japanese chars and added as a password. I don't know meaning and this is not to offend anybody. I am sorry. I able to use "net use" to mount the share with the same user name and password. I am able to do ssh login to the system using the same user name and password. I am not sure i am executing the command properly. One more thing if I give all english password it works fine. Let me know your opinion.